# Too many values in one argument case_when?

Tags: r, case-when

I am not sure why this code doesnt run. But if it breaks it into 2 smaller chunks then it works. Is there anyway i can run this whole chunk at once?

When I run this code it appears the plus sign in the console and I couldnt click run in R markdown

```
dataT4<- dataT4 %>% mutate (coupleID=case_when(id==10011~1, id==10021~2, 
id==10032~3, id==10041~4,id==10062~5, id==10071~6,id==10082~7, id==10092~8, 
id==10112~9, id==10121~10,id== 10131~11, id==10142~12, id==10151~13, 
id==10162~14,id==10171~15, id==10181~16, id==10202~17, id==10212~18, id==10221~19, 
id==10232~20, id==10242~21, id==10251~22, id==10262~23, id==10271~24, id==10292~25, 
id==10311~26, id==10332~27, id==10342~28, id==10351~29, id==10361~30, id==10372~31, 
id==10382~32, id==10391~33, id==10401~34, id==10412~35, id==10421~36, id==10432~37, 
id==10442~38, id==10452~39, id==10461~40, id==10471~41, id==10481~42, id==10492~43, 
id==10501~44, id==10511~45, id==10521~46, id==10532~47, id==10542~48, id==10562~49, 
id==10581~50, id==10592~51, id==10602~52, id==10611~53, id==10642~54, id==10651~55, 
id==10662~56, id==10672~57, id==10681~58, id==10702~59, id==10761~60, id==10782~61, 
id==10791~62, id==10802~63, id==10812~64, id==10822~65, id==10831~66, id==10852~67, 
id==10862~68, id==10881~69, id==10912~70, id==10942~71, id==10951~72, id==10962~73, 
id==10972~74, id==10982~75, id==10992~76, id==11001~77, id==11031~78, id==11052~79, 
id==11061~80, id==11072~81, id==11092~82, id==11101~83, id==11112~84, id==11171~85, 
id==11192~86, id==11202~87, id==11221~88, id==11231~89, id==11252~90, id==11261~91, 
id==11281~92, id==11292~93, id==11322~94, id==11332~95, id==11372~96, id==11382~97, 
id==11391~98, id==11411~99, id==11422~100, id==11441~101, id==11461~102, 
id==11471~103, id==11492~104, id==11501~105, id==11512~106, 
id==11521~107,id==11562~108,id==11591~109, id==11601~110, id==11611~111, 
id==11621~112, id==11632~113, id==11641~114, id==11651~115, id==11662~116, 
id==11682~117,id==11691~118,id==11712~119, id==11771~120, id==11782~121, 
id==11811~122, id==11821~123, id==11831~124, id==11841~125, id==11852~126, 
id==11861~127,id==11872~128,id==11882~129, id==11892~130, id==11902~131, 
id==11911~132, id==11922~133, id==11961~134, id==11972~135, 
id==11992~136,id==12011~137, id==12041~138, id==12052~139, id==12061~140, 
id==12081~141, id==12101~142, id==12111~143, id==12122~144, id==12131~145, 
id==12142~146, id==12151~147, id==12161~148, id==12182~149, id==12191~150, 
id==12201~151, id==12232~152, id==12261~153, id==12272~154, id==12322~155, 
id==12332~156, id==12342~157, id==12352~158, id==12382~159, id==12392~160, 
id==12401~161, id==12411~162, id==12421~163, id==12432~164, id==12441~165, 
id==12451~166, id==12461~167, id==12471~168, id==12492~169, id==12501~170, 
id==12512~171, id==12521~172, id==12542~173, id==12552~174, id==12562~175, 
id==12572~176, id==12581~177, id==12612~178, id==12622~179, id==12652~180, 
id==12662~181, id==12682~182, id==12701~183, id==12712~184, id==12731~185, 
id==12741~186, id==12762~187, id==12792~188, id==12802~189, id==12811~190, 
id==12822~191, id==12832~192, id==12841~193, id==12862~194, id==12882~195, 
id==12891~196, id==12911~197, id==12931~198, id==12942~199, id==12952~200, 
id==12961~201, id==12972~202, id==13011~203, id==13021~204, id==13032~205, 
id==13042~206, id==13061~207, id==13082~208, id==13102~209, id==13111~210, 
id==13132~211, id==13142~212, id==13151~213, id==13162~214, id==13191~215, 
id==13202~216, id==13212~217, id==13262~218, id==13271~219, id==13281~220, 
id==13311~221, id==13322~222, id==13331~223, id==13351~224, id==13361~225, 
id==13372~226, id==13422~227, id==13432~228, id==13452~229, id==13462~230, 
id==13472~231, id==13481~232, id==13501~233, id==13511~234, id==13521~235, 
id==13561~236, id==13571~237, id==13601~238, id==13612~239, id==13632~240, 
id==13642~241, id==13652~242, id==13662~243, id==13671~244, id==13681~245, 
id==13691~246, id==13701~247, id==13711~248, id==13732~249, id==13742~250, 
id==13752~251, id==13782~252, id==13842~253, id==13802~254, id==13822~255, 
id==13851~256, id==13872~257, id==13882~258, id==13892~259, id==13912~260, 
id==13921~261, id==13932~262, id==13941~263, id==13952~264, id==13971~265, 
id==13981~266, id==13992~267, id==14011~268, id==14021~269, id==14031~270, 
id==14041~271, id==14052~272, id==14072~273, id==14111~274, id==14131~275, 
id==14162~276, id==14172~277, id==14182~278, id==14191~279, id==14212~280, 
id==14222~281, id==14241~282, id==14261~283, id==14291~284, id==14302~285, 
id==14312~286, id==14321~287, id==14342~288, id==14352~289, id==14362~290, 
id==14371~291, id==14392~292, id==14402~293, id==14432~294, id==14451~295, 
id==14472~296, id==14482~297, id==14491~298, id==14511~299, id==14521~300, 
id==14531~301, id==14541~302, id==14552~303, id==14562~304, id==14572~305, 
id==14581~306, id==14592~307, id==14602~308, id==14621~309, id==14632~310, 
id==14641~311, id==14651~312, id==14671~313, id==14681~314, id==14692~315, 
id==14712~316, id==14722~317, id==14732~318, id==14741~319, id==14751~320, 
id==14781~321, id==14792~322, id==14812~323, id==14842~324, id==14852~325, 
id==14862~326, id==14882~327, id==14892~328, id==14901~329, id==11012~330))
```

Answer (score 1):

As a single line it is just too long to be parsed. You may be better served putting all of these values into a separate `data.frame` and merging it into your data instead of using a giant `case_when`.

Usually when I want to do something like this I'll open Excel or something similar, put column names in the first row (here that would be `id` and `couple_id`) and enter all of the values, save it as a CSV, then read the CSV into R as a `data.frame`, and then merge it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank`:

```
dataT4 <- data.frame(id=c(10011, 10021, 10382, 11012))

dataT4 <- dataT4 %>% mutate (coupleID=rank(id))
dataT4 
     id coupleID
1 10011        1
2 10021        2
3 10382        3
4 11012        4
```

---

**Data**:

```
dataT4 <- data.frame(id=c(10011, 10021, 10382, 11012))
```